# Adding background image to create-react-native project

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to insert a background image into my create-react-native project. I would like to be able to add this image: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/80/29/a9/8029a9bf324c79b4803e1e5a2aba25f3--costume-makeup-iphone-wallpaper.jpg. I have tried applying it to the stylesheet but it is not accepting the background-image tag. I am very new at react.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import ListItem from "/Users/Westin/assignment5/ListItem";


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state ={
    thing: "",
    things: [],
  };

  thingValueChanged = value =>{
    //alert(value);
    this.setState({
      thing: value
    });
  }

  onClickingAdd = () =>
  {
    if(this.state.thing === "")
    {
      return;
    }

    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          things: prevState.things.concat(prevState.thing)
        };

    });
  }



  render() {
    const thingsOut = this.state.things.map((thing,i) => (<ListItem key = {i} thing={thing} />))
    
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
       <Text style={styles.headerText}>My Favourite Things</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput 
      value={this.state.thing}
      placeholder="Add your favourite things" 
      style={styles.inputbox}
      onChangeText={this.thingValueChanged}
      />
      <Button
      title="Add"
      style={styles.addButton}
      onPress = {this.onClickingAdd}
      
      />
      </View>
      <View>
        {thingsOut}
        </View>


      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e6eeff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  header: {
    padding: 10,
    
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#003cb3',
  },
  inputbox: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 40,
    width: "70%",
  },
  addButton: {
    width: "30%"
  },
  input: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "center",
  }
});
```

This is the code I tried to run

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import ListItem from "/Users/Westin/assignment5/ListItem";

const remote = 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/80/29/a9/8029a9bf324c79b4803e1e5a2aba25f3--costume-makeup-iphone-wallpaper.jpg';

export default class BackgroundImage extends Component {
  render() {
    const resizeMode = 'center';

    return (
      <Image
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          resizeMode,
        }}
        source={{ uri: remote }}
      />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BackgroundImage', () => BackgroundImage);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state ={
    thing: "",
    things: [],
  };

  thingValueChanged = value =>{
    //alert(value);
    this.setState({
      thing: value
    });
  }

  onClickingAdd = () =>
  {
    if(this.state.thing === "")
    {
      return;
    }

    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          things: prevState.things.concat(prevState.thing)
        };

    });
  }



  render() {
    const thingsOut = this.state.things.map((thing,i) => (<ListItem key = {i} thing={thing} />))
    
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
       <Text style={styles.headerText}>My Favourite Things</Text>        
      </View>

      <View style={styles.input}>
      <TextInput 
      value={this.state.thing}
      placeholder="Add your favourite things" 
      style={styles.inputbox}
      onChangeText={this.thingValueChanged}
      />
      <Button
      title="Add"
      style={styles.addButton}
      onPress = {this.onClickingAdd}
 
      />
      </View>
      <View>
        {thingsOut}
        </View>


      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    opacity: 0.5,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  header: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#003cb3',
  },
  inputbox: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 40,
    width: "70%",
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
  addButton: {
    width: "30%"
  },
  input: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "center",
  }
});
```

It said I cant run two export classes

Comment: Can you show what code you've tried? I don't see a reference to that image anywhere in the code you've posted.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post on here

Comment: It only allows a certain number of characters, my code does not fit in comments

Comment: I added it to an edit

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <ImageBackground source=
                { {uri: 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/80/29/a9/8029a9bf324c79b4803e1e5a2aba25f3--costume-makeup-iphone-wallpaper.jpg' } }
            style={styles.container}
                >
                <Text>Some</Text>
                <Text>Text</Text>
        <Text>Centered</Text>
        <Text>In</Text>
                <Text>Columns</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '100%'
    },
});
```

You can read more about `<ImageBackground/>` here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#background-image-via-nesting

[image: Android screenshot]

Comment: I tried this and kept receiving an error: Unable to resolve /Users/Westin/assignment5/background" from "./C:\\Users\\Westin\\assignment5\\App.js`: The module `/Users/Westin/assignment5/background` could not be found"

Comment: background is the name of my photo

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying it and cannot get it to work with either the `require()` syntax, nor with the `{ uri: '...' }` syntax. Weird, let me spend some time seeing if there is a work around.

Comment: The provided sample works for me (with react-native `~0.55.2` inside my package.json). Make sure yours is equivalent.

Comment: It does not look like you can wrap the `<ImageBackground>` inside a `<View>` without it hiding the background image, so you need to use a style like I provided applied to the `<ImageBackground>`. YMMV.

Comment: I tried using this method but it makes the actual application disappear. I need the background to sit behind it. In this case it causes it to shift the rest of the application.

Comment: The `<View>` tags are conflicting with the `<ImageBackground>` tag. I recommend stripping out the behavior (the onPress, etc.) and focusing on your view structures. Here is a starting point: https://gist.github.com/xrd/9ad61dad432d39aec28e967619859e9f. This renders the background image you want. You should play with the styles and see if you can get all the subcomponents within the image background to layout properly.

Comment: To be more clear, there is something about the "flex" attribute in the CSS that is obscuring the background image component. If you remove that from the style, it works (more or less). So, I think you just need to move your styles that are in the views, into the ImageBackground which wraps around the other components and replaces the `<View>` components. You are getting close, don't quit!